# Python read file methods memory?

Tags: python, memory

I usually read the file with below code

```
r = open('test.txt', mode='rt')
for line in r:
    print(line)
```

What if test.txt is huge enough and it is appended continuously
Then is the code above read by it reaches the end of test.txt?
Or it just stop when it reaches the end of test.txt at the time it starts to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File iterators make use of a constant-sized buffer to limit the number of I/O calls. Data is only read from disk once the iterator reaches the end of the current buffer, at which point another large chunk is read into memory.

Comment: Sounds hard to understand. Could you explain a bit more specifically. Or could you recommend any document to reference it.

Comment: Basically, you won't read the entire file into memory at once, only enough to satisfy at least one iteration. It doesn't really matter if the file grows, since the iterator doesn't really know or care how big the file is in the first place.

Comment: If you happen to read the *last* line before the file is appended to again, the iterator will terminate. It's impossible to tell just by reading whether the writer is truly done or simply preparing to write more.

Answer (score 0):

It is a operating system issue actually which you can read from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41719

It depends on how operating system runs writing and reading procedures. If the writer process fast enough then probably it will keep reading. However if the reading process is faster than it will read end-of-file and close it.

Therefore it is unpredictable due to scheduling.

Comment: Python will do some buffering as well, so it's not entirely OS dependent.